# what wrong with my latex

Tags: beamer, pdf, animate

I try to find the mistake but i'm....

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \newcounter{goc}
        \setcounter{goc}{0}
        \begin{animateinline}[auto,loop]{20}
            \whiledo{\thegoc<50}
            {\begin{tikzpicture}[join=round,\bfseries]
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\g}{2.5-abs(2.5-0.1*\thegoc)}
                    \clip(-8,-2.5)rectangle (8,2.5);
                    \path(0,1)node[red,scale=2,yscale=\g]{SỬ DỤNG ANIMATE};
                    \path(0,0)node[green,scale=2,yscale=\g]{TẠO HÌNH ĐỘNG};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \stepcounter{goc}
                \ifthenelse{\thegoc<50}{\newframe}{\end{animateinline}}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean?????

Comment: After I backfill the missing `\end{animateinline}` instruction before `\end{frame}`, I get the following error message: "Package xkeyval Error: `auto'` undefined in families `anim@user'`", followed by "See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation." Since you haven't stated what it is that you're looking to achieve, I'm afraid I can't provide any further suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

1. Don't use `\whiledo`  for building a loop around parameterized animation frames
2. `\bfseries`-->`font=\bfseries`
3. `auto`-->`autoplay`

```latex
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{20}
    \multiframe{50}{i=0+1}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[join=round,font=\bfseries]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\g}{2.5-abs(2.5-0.1*\i)}
        \useasboundingbox(-4,-1)rectangle (4,2);
        \path(0,1)node[red,xscale=2,yscale=\g]{SỬ DỤNG ANIMATE};
        \path(0,0)node[green,xscale=2,yscale=\g]{TẠO HÌNH ĐỘNG};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Seems the ends of instances of the environment `animateinline` are detected in a special way where the phrase `\end{animateinline}` needs to be found "directly", i.e., without having things expanded that form the "body" of an instance of the environment.
- The `tikzpicture`-environment's optional argument does not have a key `\bfseries`.
- With `animateinline`'s optional argument there is no key `auto` but a key `autoplay`.
- I suggest not having each frame define the counter `goc` but have that counter defined in the preamble.
- I suppose you need to compile at least twice without deleting auxiliary files between compilations.

Perhaps the following does the trick—please let me know if things work out as currently I cannot test myself: I am currently working with a tablet computer that does not have a decent pdf viewer installed that could display animations.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Probably you don't need this as your setup does it in any case:
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{animate}
\newcounter{goc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}%
    \setcounter{goc}{0}%
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{20}%
    \whiledo{\thegoc<50}{%
       \begin{tikzpicture}[join=round, font=\bfseries]%
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\g}{2.5-abs(2.5-0.1*\thegoc)}%
       \clip(-8,-2.5)rectangle (8,2.5);%
       \path(0,1)node[red,scale=2,yscale=\g]{SỬ DỤNG ANIMATE};%
       \path(0,0)node[green,scale=2,yscale=\g]{TẠO HÌNH ĐỘNG};%
       \end{tikzpicture}%
       \stepcounter{goc}%
       \ifthenelse{\thegoc<50}{\newframe}{}%
    }%
    \end{animateinline}%
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```